# AbortController and fetch: how to distinguish network error from abort error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

So I have a fetch with an abort controller like so:

```js
async function fn() {
  const abortController = new AbortController();

  try {
    const response = await fetch(/* ... */, { signal: abortController.signal });
    // ...
  } catch (e) {
    // how can I tell if `e` is from a network error (e.g. offline)
    // or an error from an abort
  }
}
```

How can I tell if `e` is a network error or an abort error?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
abortController.signal.aborted
```

will tell you if the `AbortSignal` fired.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/aborted

Alternatively if the error `name` prop is `'AbortError'`

```
e.name === 'AbortError'
```

you can detect from the error alone, but beware:

> [Current version of Firefox rejects the promise with a DOMException](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal)

Therefore, checking `abortController.signal.aborted` seems like the safest.

Comment: How to tell if error is caused by browser aborting request (e.g. on page reload)? In that case it is still TypeError.